# Convert angle (of shadow) and distance (from shadow to text) to a text-shadow effect dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I want to dynamically calculate a text-shadow effect based on a given angle and a distance in pixels.

How can I combine those two values (using script, dynamically) into text-shadow effect?

Comment: Using a generator tool such as https://css3gen.com/text-shadow is the easiest way to see how your parameters affect the outcome.

Comment: Yes, but I want to change it using script, dynamically

Comment: Change your question to say so then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little math can help you figure it out. Trigonometry.

If you remember from math class

```
cos(x) = adjacent/hypotenuse

sin(x) = opposite/hypotenuse.
```

Using this you can figure out what you want. x is your angle (270 in your example). the hypotenuse is your distance (4 in your example). Solve for Adjacent and opposite and you'll get your x and y translates. add in the blur and color of your choice and you get:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#evalButton").click(function(){
    var degrees = $("#degrees").val();
    var distance = $("#distance").val();
    var blur = $("#blur").val();
    var color = $("#color").val();
    var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    var xDistance = Math.cos(radians) * distance;
    var yDistance = Math.sin(radians) * distance;
    $(".sample").css({
      "text-shadow": xDistance + "px "+
                     yDistance + "px "+
                     blur + "px #"+color
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.sample{
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Degrees: <input type="number" id="degrees" value="270"/></label>
<br>
<label>Distance: <input type="number" id="distance" value="4"/></label>
<br>
<label>Blur: <input type="number" id="blur" value="2"/></label>
<br>
<label>Color: <input type="text" id="color" value="444"/></label>
<br>
<button type="button" id="evalButton">Calculate</button>

<div class="sample"> Text With Shadow </div>
```

This could easily be changed into a function that takes the inputs are arguments. If you want to measure your angle from a different spot, simply add your offset to the degrees after we pull in the value from the box.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: No problem. That was fun practice. :D